# How to add description to Image collection in meteor.js ( client side & server side)

Tags: javascript, image, meteor

*I tried in client side*

`Images.insert({art:"some description"},{ _id:this._id});`

got this error

**​cfs_data-man.js:241 Uncaught Error: DataMan constructor received data that it doesn't support(…)**

---

`Images.update({art:"some description"},{ _id:"XztX47mZ2EYcjHdMp"});`

and got this error:

***collection.js:395 Uncaught errorClass {error: 403, reason: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID.", details: undefined, message: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}*​**

Comment: Switch those objects, first is search, second is what you update

Answer (score 1):

assuming you're using CollectionFS, when you insert an image save the _id and then update the document by `_id`

```
imgId = Images.insert(...);
Images.update({ _id: imgId },{ $set: { description: "my awesome selfie" }});
```

Comment: I think he's using autopublish he did should (remove)[https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe] before going in production.